# Prove that the nth root converges to 1 with Binominal Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove with the use of the Binominal Theorem that:

> **$$\sqrt{x}=(\sqrt[n] {\sqrt{x}})^x=(\sqrt[x] {\sqrt{x}}-1)+1)^x≥1+x(\sqrt[n] {\sqrt{x}}-1) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{N} $$**
>
> This is the first step to prove that the sequence $\sqrt[n] {x}\to1 $.

I have gotten so far:

By using the Binominal Theorem the inequality can be written as: 
$$((\sqrt[n] {\sqrt{x}}-1)+1)^x= \sum_{l=0}^x \binom xl(\sqrt[n] {\sqrt{x}}-1)^{l}≥\binom x2(\sqrt[n] {\sqrt{x}}-1)^2$$

If n≥2 then this inequality holds true.

The last part of the inequality can be written as:

$$\binom x2(\sqrt[n] {\sqrt{x}}-1)^2 = \frac {x(x-1)}2(\sqrt[n] {\sqrt{x}}-1)^2 $$

Therefore: 
$\sqrt{x}≥ \frac {x(x-1)}2(\sqrt[n] {\sqrt{x}}-1)^2. $

This is where I get stuck, what would be the next logical step from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little simpler than you are making it....

$$
\begin{align}
((\sqrt[x] {\sqrt{x}}-1)+1)^x &= \sum_{\ell=0}^x \binom x\ell(\sqrt[x] {\sqrt{x}}-1)^{\ell} \\
&\ge \binom x0(\sqrt[x] {\sqrt{x}}-1)^0 + \binom x1(\sqrt[x] {\sqrt{x}}-1)^1 \\
&=1+ x(\sqrt[x] {\sqrt{x}}-1)  
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That was a much simpler way to do it, thank you for the help!